# Getting Error: You've reached your account limit of 3 concurrent processes with Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I tried to run the following command :

(venv)prajjwal@ubuntu:~/herokuDjango$ **heroku run python manage.py shell**

```
Running `python manage.py shell` attached to terminal... failed 
!    You've reached your account limit of 3 concurrent processes.
!    Please verify your account at http://heroku.com/verify to have this limit increased
```

I looked it up on Heroku website:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits

But It says under the following subtopic 
Concurrent one-off dynos
that:
"Heroku accounts that aren’t verified cannot have more than 3 one-off dynos running concurrently."

But where exactly are my 3 one-off dynos running?

Comment: run `heroku ps` and you'll see what's running on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call the `heroku run` command, you're actually creating a one-off dyno. Those dynos can last up to an hour at a time before they're shut down. So if you've called it 3 times, there's a chance that all three are still "alive" in the sense that resources are still allocated to your now, non-running process. If you want to test out your process, try running locally with `foreman`.

Take a look at their documentation for one-off dynos. That should explain the purpose and use case behind them.

Answer (score 6):

Try typing

```
heroku ps
```

Then type

```
heroku ps:stop run.xxxx
```

where xxxx is the # of the dyno that you want to kill.

Comment: Or you just run `heroku ps:stop run.` to kill all dynos!